# Is there a minimum duration requirement for employement contract when applying for a Blue Card through Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, schengen, blue-card

Company managed to send the contract for 8 months instead of 1 year. I have appointment on Monday. There is a frequent mention of "at least 1 year employement contract" however these are from unofficial sources.

Please throw some light. Shall I just apply or wait for a correction. I meet every other requirements and company rushing me to get the visa asap and start to work.

Comment: What happened?  My advice would have been "go to the interview and ask the official".  You could answer your own question if you did.

Comment: @MartinBonner they did not seem much concerned over contract period however they told me application is for work visa and blue card granted if requirements are met. I guess I will have to wait and see what I will receive, work visa or blue card